# Formatting the output of a C++ program

Tags: c++

I have already written most of the code for the problem and it works. I'm just unsure of how to format the output.

Problem : Design and develop a C++ program for Calculating e(n) when `delta <= 0.000001`

```
e(n-1) = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + … + 1/(n-1)!

e(n) = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + … + 1/(n)!

delta = e(n) – e(n-1)
```

You do not have any input to the program. Your output should be something like this:

> N = 2 e(1) = 2 e(2) = 2.5 delta = 0.5
>
> N = 3 e(2) = 2.5 e(3) = 2.565 delta = 0.065

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//3! = 3 * 2!
//2! = 2 * 1! 
//1! = 1
int factorial(int number) 
{
    //if number is <= 1, return 1
    if (number <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    // otherwise multiply number by factorial(number - 1)
    else
    {
            //otherwise multiply number by factorial(number - 1) and return it
        int temp = number * factorial(number - 1);
        cout << "factorial of " << number << " = " << temp << endl;
            return temp;
    }
}

double sumOfFactorials(int n) 
{
    double sum = 0;
    //loop from 1..n, adding the factorial division to a sum
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        double dividedValue = 1.00000 / factorial(i);
        cout << fixed;
        sum = sum + dividedValue;
    }
    return sum;
}

/**
* Compute the sum of 1 + ... + 1/(n!)
* input number: 1
* output number: 1 + ... + 1/(input!)
*/
double e(int n) 
{
    double value = 1 + sumOfFactorials(n);
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "e:" << e(3) << endl; // 1 + sumOfFactorials(3)
    cout << "sumOfFactorials: " << sumOfFactorials(3) << endl; //0 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3!
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is your actual question is. Can you pelase elaborate more?

Comment: When I run the program, I get values for the inputs I have but I need to establish where to put in E and delta so I get output from the program similar to what is up top. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: I see you have all the code written, so you just need to format the answer to match to the given format. am I correct?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it. I'm just unsure of where it should go.

Comment: Check the answer, I hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right code, All you need is to format the output. Just modify the `main()` method. here is a snippet you can try.

NOTE : There is an error in the precision of the answer, I think you can correct it.

PS : Please uncomment your debugging `cout` lines.

```
int main()
{


for(int i = 2; i<4; i++){

    double en_1 = e(i-1);
    double en = e(i);
    double delta = en - en_1;

    cout << "N = "<<i;
    cout << " e("<< (i-1) <<") = " << en_1;
    cout << " e("<< (i) <<") = " << en;

    cout << "delta = " << delta;
    cout << "\n";
}   



}
```